# is there an easy way to convert custom letters from a .png file to illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I have made a custom title for my game. Because it exist out of two colors, I decided to make it in paint because I find it handy for pixel art. I would like to port this to Adobe Illustrator so I can make different sizes of it.

My problem is: Do I have to trace the whole text with the line segment/ pencil tool or is there an easier way to do it?

**edit:** If I use image trace it gets all kind of round shapes, i just need it traced like in this attached picture

[image]

Comment: To be really accurate, it often requires manual creation rather than automated tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Simply Trace them in illustrator !!! And do a gray or black and white trace and then simply put a stroke around it with the same color as green.

Comment: i wish it worked that way, but it just doesn't trace right. i got all kinds of round letters instead of just plain 8 bit style

Comment: You can always use the Simplify option to get rid of Curves and roundness of the letters. Set it to Straight lines and play with it.

Comment: Trace it but import the image in Illustrator at very big size. It can be low resolution dpi. There will be less "round corners" at bigger size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would take too long to re-create this type with the rectangle tool (M) then combine the shapes with the path-finder panel. Each letter is only like 4 or 5 rectangles. Then use a path offset (Object -> Path -> Offset path) to create the stroke.

This will assure you're getting the best results.

I was able to bring the graphic into Illustrator and draw shapes over the type logo.

This is the bottom of the first letter. The blue is the rectangle I was using to draw over the type.

[image: screenshot of the type logo]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Photoshop, you can make quick selections with the magic wand, covert those to paths, then from the File Menu - choose **Export/Paths to Illustrator**.

I suggest just making a path for the black letters. Once you have the piece in Illustrator, make your compound paths, set them to black and add a green stroke.

You'll might still have to clean it up a bit, but it would be pretty quick.